# Swift empty callbacks - performance impact

Tags: swift, callback

I am new to iOS and Swift development and I'm not sure If I understand correctly the way callbacks work.

As I understand the callbacks are the same delegate methods but are resolved immediately in the code place.

I would like to have in my controllers some callbacks which would or would not be called depending on some conditions, but I'm not sure regarding the performance.

If the callback does not get called will it hang in memory and wait for an answer ? And how to "cancel" the callback if it is not needed to be called?

I would not like to have to check every time in every callback across all the controllers if I returned nil or not. I want to just call the callback if it's needed and avoid doing it if it's not.

Please advice.

Comment: If a function is written in the forest and nobody calls it, does it make a sound?

Comment: :) I was not seeing the closures as another kind of "variables"/reference which disappear once the scope that encompasses them ends, that's why I was not able to understand that it will no be hanging somewhere in the air.
Tnx for the natural comparison